# Location of (permanently) deleted minor versions from OneNote file

Tags: document-library, versioning, onenote

currently in our company environment we have OneNote Online file stored in our SharePoint 2013 (site assets) and on OneDrive:

-https://XXX.XXXX.net/sites/pl-p46/SiteAssets/Showroom%20PL%20Notebook?Web=1
and
-https://my.XXX.XXXX.net/my/pl_username/Documents/myOneNote?Web=1

On this field we are experiencing interesting behaviour with versioning, creating and deleting versions and quota level for particular site collection.

We have been testing deleting minor versions from both the sharepoint stored OneNote file and OneDrive stored OneNote file. The thing is, deleting the versions does not decrease the overall site collection quota even if the version is permanently deleted. Therefore the only way out for massively growing OneNote files is to increase the quota for SC what we of cource don't want to do permanently due to massive back-ups needs.

My questions basically concerns where the (permanently) deleted versions (or their metadata) are stored.